# How to change the language of the TexShop interface in Mac OS?

Tags: languages, texshop

My Mac OS system language is Chinese. When I used the new version of TexShop, I found that the interface language is Chinese, however, some translation seems to be strange. For example, both "Tag" and "Label" are translated to "标签", which makes it harder to use. Also, when I try to ask a question, I need to make the interface to be in English to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Please get in touch with the author of TeXShop and let him know of the translation problem.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Great idea. I have sent the author an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution.
In the new Mac OS Catalina, I am able to change the interface language for a specific app in system settings (Language and Region). And then switch to the App tab to add your preference.